# How to set literals after Dart 2.2

Tags: dart, literals

Set literals were not supported until 2.2, How to set literals after Dart 2.2. Please feel free to comment. Thank you.

```
class item_t {
  String name;
  int weight;
  int value;
}

main() {
  const List<item_t> items = [
    {'map', 9, 1}, // reports errors
  ];
}
```

**update 1**

I could define the list as a serial of define statements. However, it seems it is ineffective.

```
class item_t {
  String name;
  int weight;
  int value;
}

main() {
  // final item_t items = new item_t(100);
  List<item_t> items = new List(2);

  items[0].name = 'map';
  items[0].weight = 9;
  items[0].value = 1;

}
```

In C language, I can define a structure effectively but I don't know how to do that in dart.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int weight;
    int value;
} item_t;

item_t items[] = {
    {"map",                      9,   150},
    {"compass",                 13,    35},
    {"water",                  153,   200},
};
```

**update 2**

Thank you jamesdlin's advise, I can simplify the list initialization and access the element by index. However, it still can't be as effective as C language.

```
 var mySet = [
    {"map", 9, 150},
    {"compass", 13, 35},
    {"water", 153, 200},
    {"sandwich", 50, 160},
    {"glucose", 15, 60},
    {"tin", 68, 45},
    {"banana", 27, 60},
    {"apple", 39, 40},
    {"cheese", 23, 30},
    {"beer", 52, 10},
    {"suntan cream", 11, 70},
    {"camera", 32, 30},
    {"T-shirt", 24, 15},
    {"trousers", 48, 10},
    {"umbrella", 73, 40},
    {"waterproof trousers", 42, 70},
    {"waterproof overclothes", 43, 75},
    {"note-case", 22, 80},
    {"sunglasses", 7, 20},
    {"towel", 18, 12},
    {"socks", 4, 50},
    {"book", 30, 10}
  ];

  print(mySet[0].elementAt(1));
```

Comment: Separate questions should be asked separately instead of updating an existing question.  I never saw your updates, but if you want the equivalent of a C `struct`, you should just create a Dart `class` with a a constructor.  Yes, it will be slightly less convenient than C since you would need to explicitly type the class/constructor name for each element.

Answer (score 13):

You use `{` and `}` to specify `Set` (and `Map`) literals:

```dart
var mySet = {1, 2, 3};
```

Note that to avoid ambiguity with `Map` literals, you must explicitly specify a type when creating an empty set.  For example:

```dart
var emptySet = <int>{};
```

Also see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#sets

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `{` and `}` with `[` and `]`, respectively, and everything will work fine.