# What is the best way to store and import a large multidimensional list in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm willing to create a very large list of all of the Brazilian football teams. My list should have more than one dimension, so it can store the club's name, its colours, city and so on. Since it will be a huge list, I decided to store it in a different file, which was created just to store it. The file is called `club_list.dart` and goes like this:

```
var clubs = {
  [
    [
      'Flamengo',
      'red',
      'Rio de Janeiro',
    ],
    'Botafogo',
    'Vasco',
    'Fluminense',
    'São Paulo',
    'Santos',
    'Corinthias',
    'Palmeiras',
    'Cruzeiro',
    'Atlético-MG',
    'Cruzeiro',
    'Internacional',
    'Grêmio'
  ]
};
```

So it has 3 dimensions for now, and is only completed for the first club. The first question is: **This is the best way to create and store a multidimensional list on dart? It is faster to create a json file or something else instead of a dart file on this case?**

**And after creating the file, how do I use it on my project?** I tried importing the dart file but the program says `clubs is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to be clear, the following syntax:

`var a = {1,2,3}`

Is creating a [Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518412/10746978), not a List.

So in your case, `clubs`is a Set with 1 element (A list).

You can delete the external `{}` so it becomes a List:

`List clubs = [.....]`

For multi-dimensional Lists, you can use a few packages which may wrap this functionality for you. (Like [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/piecemeal/latest/piecemeal/Array2D-class.html), or [this](https://pub.dev/packages/smart_arrays_numerics)). However, even though some of them might implement it as a single array internally, the gain from it mostly comes from comprehension and optimising numerical calculations involving it. So in your case I don't think it will make a huge difference. You can create a List normally and you will be fine.

There is no problem in creating a large list in dart. Large is relative. This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/english_words) for example has 5000 most used words from english language in a single dart [constant](https://github.com/filiph/english_words/blob/master/lib/src/words/all.dart). And it's well scored (94 out of 100).

> It is faster to create a json file or something else instead of a dart file on this case?

I don't think its faster to use it as a Json, since you will need a medium layer to translate it to a Dart map. It will be better for encapsulation and integration with other programs that might use it, and for maintenance since there are a lot of Json editors available. But not strictly faster.

> And after creating the file, how do I use it on my project?

Try using it as a const (or final as suggested in other answer):

`const List clubs = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You can set as final

```
final List CLUBS = {
  [
    [
      'Flamengo',
      'red',
      'Rio de Janeiro',
    ],
    'Botafogo',
    'Vasco',
    'Fluminense',
    'São Paulo',
    'Santos',
    'Corinthias',
    'Palmeiras',
    'Cruzeiro',
    'Atlético-MG',
    'Cruzeiro',
    'Internacional',
    'Grêmio'
  ]
};
}
```